# What are the advantages of using JS over the backend to save a draft using a button?

Tags: javascript, forms, backend

I have a 'create a blog post' form and am going to implement the ability to 'Save Draft'. A draft post has no value for published_at and a post is published after the published_at date is passed.

Is it better to use JS for the logic or to work it all out in the backend?

```
<input class="form-control" name="published_at" type="text" id="published_at">
<button type="button">Save Draft</button>
<input type="submit" value="Publish">
```

Comment: Well, what's your use case? Who's your audience? What browser support can you expect?

Comment: Both. JavaScript storage is tied to a specific machine, and networks and servers become unavailable. Each compensates for the failure modes of the others.

Comment: In general it is better do *everything* in the backend and use JS only for [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). If you already have a serverside logic for storing posts, adding the logic for storing drafts shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: It is an online course I am doing, the instructor uses JS to describe the action of the save draft button but it could easily be achieved in the backend so wanted to understand the advantages of the JS way.

Answer (score 3):

I would say mix them. Use JS to send the draft to the server and save it with your backend language.

That way you don't interrupt the user while writing by refreshing the page. You could go even further and use JS to auto save drafts every N seconds.

Something like this could be an idea:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // if changes have been made since last.
  // send ajax to server and store new version of draft.
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: To add to the answer, you can use `onBeforeUnload` listener instead of timeout and send final cut to server. This way, you will get the data on submit or on exit. But considering that this event may not be called, you can combine both approaches.

Comment: Yes, that is good advice. And it's also nice to have a button even though you auto save. Some people like pressing that button to make sure everything is saved.